# Qualtrics: How do I pipe words that have been previously piped and ranked?

Tags: javascript, pipe, ranking, qualtrics

My survey has participants select words from a list. These words get piped into a question where participants rank them. I want these ranked words to appear later in the study (via piping). On its own, Qualtrics cannot pipe new ranked words that have been previously piped into a ranking question. **Is there Javascript that will allow me to do that?** Thank you in advance!

Piping this "${q://QID62/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}" does not save the new ranked word
Piping this "${q://QID61/ChoiceDescription/8}" saves the ranking "8" but not the word ranked 8.

The survey has participants select 15 words from 50 by carrying forward the choices. The chosen words are piped into a rank question.
Say I select funny, selfish, and kind and they appear piped into the ranking question like this:
2 funny
4 selfish
9 kind

then they get re-ranked as:
6 funny
7 selfish
8 kind

Ultimately, I want these words to appear as piped text in a "Descriptive Text" question:
Bob is funny. Bob is selfish. Bob is kind.